# Assetic watch suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I have issues using the php app/console assetic:watch (assetic:dump --watch) command since this morning.

Thursday everything was fine and this morning the command does not see the changes when I update a file. assetic:dump works fine but I don't want to wait the 20 seconds each time I update a css (less) file.

Has anyone an idea of what is happening ?

I already rebooted and cleared the cache of symfony.

I use linux Mint (debian based) and cleared the /tmp folder.

(Excuse my bad, english, it's not my main language)

Comment: If you've answered your Question yourself please write an answer to your own question how you've resolved it an accept it when you can (after 2 days), so there's no unsolved question in the system which in fact has been solved. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue by erasing the assetic file in the /tmp folder right before re-launching the watch command.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem a few times.

My guess is that if the watch process is running, and it terminates unexpectedly(reboot, vagrant halt, etc), the cache remains in /tmp, and if you rerun the process, the new command will see all assets as being already watched.

Regardless, the solution you offered is valid, so removing the folder "/tmp/assetic_watch_*" forces assetic to reparse all assets.